# Discrete Time Markov Chain almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, markov-chains, self-learning

How can I prove that following quantity
$$
\frac1m\sum _{i=1}^m \mathbb1\{X(i)=j|X(0)=j \}
$$
 converges almost surely to $\frac{1}{u_{jj}}$, where $X(n)$ is DTMC, $u_{jj}$ is expected number of steps getting back to state $j$ given $X(0)=j$ and $\mathbb1$ is indicator function.

Comment: Assuming the chain is ergodic, that is?

Comment: @Math1000 yes, it is ergodic